# How to group by in MongoDB by a specific array slot?

Tags: mongodb

I have the following document structure:

```
{ "product": "x",
  "category": [ {"name": "y1", "id": "z1"},
        {"name": "y2", "id": "z2"}]
}
```

How can I group by only the first value of the array, for example "category[0]"? I have tried both "category.0" and "category[0]" and the returned result is only a single group with all documents in it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MongoDB 2.2 you can use the $unwind operator, for example:

```
db.test.aggregate( {$project : {product:1, category:1}}, {$unwind: "$category"},{$group: {_id: "$category.name", productsPerCategory: {$sum:1}}})
```

The aggregation framework is described here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/

Comment: Works great, thank you! by the way for pymongo users, you need to wrap all params in an array.